# Resolving Git Merge Conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Working in git with limited 8-10 years experience using CVS needing to understand what git repo is doing.

I created a branch off master with changes that I committed and then pushed back to master. Now in the same project I created another branch with a different change to one of the same files.  As I go to create a Pull Request for my latest `branch B` it shows commits from `Branch A`.  Also, my master shows commits from `Branch A` as though they still need to be pushed. I'd like `Branch B` to only include the changes I made since creating that branch. Then clear out the commits that are already in master showing they still need to be pushed. How do I do that? Please help.

I have tried

```
git checkout <branchA>

git rebase master
```

This was to get this branch to rebase seeing the commits were in this branch. 
Is there a way a `git reset -soft <branchB>` would remove the commits from `BranchA`?

Comment: So you've made commits to master in error? And branchA has those same commits?

Comment: Did you branch `Branch B` off from master or from `Branch A`? If it branched off from `Branch A`, it will naturally contain all of its history.

Comment: @kowsky I created off of master for a PR with just the new Branch B.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No master should have Branch A merged with (pull request approved).

Comment: Are you using github or some other repository hosting location?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Using git repository. I use source control tools and the changes from cmd line.

Comment: Sure thing. You should know that Git doesn’t support pull requests. For that you need a git repo hosting tool. Can you also clarify if you want to replace UAT _completely_ or if you do wish to merge?

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is to get in UAT. While it needs to be in master soon User Acceptance Testing would suffice.

Comment: Well your choice is to merge (use both changes), rebase (replay changes onto a branch), or reset (change the UAT branch to be master and forget the UAT branch).